# Exception in Jcloud Blobstore Filesystem File Upload

Tags: java, servlets, blobstore, jclouds

I am trying to create a small webpage for uploading single/multiple files using jsp & servlets.

I am using jcloud Blobstore Filesystem api, apache tomcat server and Eclipse for the development environment.

I am getting an exception in my Servlet file in doPost function when I am trying to create a container using function

> createContainerInLocation (null, container_name)

Please check the exception stack trace attached.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jclouds.filesystem.strategy.internal.FilesystemStorageStrategyImpl.createContainerInLocation(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jclouds/domain/Location;Lorg/jclouds/blobstore/options/CreateContainerOptions;)Z
at org.jclouds.blobstore.config.LocalBlobStore.createContainerInLocation(LocalBlobStore.java:399)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.inject.internal.DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocationHandler.java:37)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy235.createContainerInLocation(Unknown Source)
at com.binfer.FileUpload.doPost(FileUpload.java:59)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which version of jclouds are you using?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of jclouds dependencies in your Maven pom.xml?

Comment: Yes I had different versions of jcloud dependencies. I removed them, and kept only one which I need. It worked. Thank you all for the reply.